# Getting all requests while loading website

Tags: flutter, http, dart, request, response

In my Flutter app...
I was wondering if it would be possible if I could get all the requests a website was requesting. I want something like chrome dev tools offers:

[image]

Let's say I would call a HTTP request to a website and then I would receive requested data and these request that were made while loading the web.

Answer (score 1):

You have to study how to work a webserver and the client / server architecture.
To make it easier for you, the client makes a request in a specific path to the web server, the web server provides a response, the client processes the data and, if necessary, makes other requests to complete its "task".
In chrome dev tools, you see only a log/debugger of requests.
To get all requestes, you need to simulate a complete functional client, or get from response the specific information you want.
I link you one package in Dart and one in NodeJS to start understading what you need, [web_scarper_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/web_scraper), [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)